# How free are Cuban citizens to leave the country these days?

Tags: communism, cuba

I know that it used to be the case that the Cuban authorities prevented people from leaving the country that they deemed useful - similar to Eastern Germany.

I heard that this was lifted a couple of years ago, but I have no source as to precisely how the state of affairs really is.

Does somebody have more information, preferably backed with either first-hand experience or links to credible sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2013, Cuban authorities have scrapped the exit visa requirement.

According to [an article by The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jan/15/cuba-relaxes-travel-restrictions), Cubans can now exit the countries freely. Cubans can stay overseas 2 years, up from the original 11 months without losing residency back home. However, the ability to travel overseas still depends on foreign governments' willingness to grant visa to Cuban citizens.

---

This [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-21008571) does list some restrictions on exiting the country. 'Athletes and "vital" professionals as well as Communist Party leaders' may be denied passports unless they have authorisation according to a senior Cuban immigration officer.

This commentary (written before the ease of exit restrictions) by The Economist states that:

> People who skills are considered vital, such as **doctors and teachers**, will probably have to wait several years before getting one.
>
> *(emphasise mine)*

Another [article by The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/dec/01/cuba-reimpose-travel-permit-requirement-doctors?0p19G=c) quotes:

> “The migration of Cuban health professionals is a concern for the country,” the government announcement read, blaming US laws that aid Cuban medical emigration for having “the perverse objective of pushing Cuban health professionals to abandon their missions in other countries”.

---

Other than that, it seems that Cuban citizens can travel freely. Citizens holding a Cuban passport can travel to 78 countries visa-free, according to [Henley & Partners Visa Restrictions Index 2016](https://www.henleyglobal.com/files/download/HP/hvri/HP%20Visa%20Restrictions%20Index%20160223.pdf), topping India (52) and China (50).

Comment: Interesting, but I'd be especially interested in what the restrictions to "vital professionals" are in practice regarding emigration.

Comment: @John Thanks, I've found another article by The Guardian which describes the reason, and how it specifically affected Cuban doctors -- https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/dec/01/cuba-reimpose-travel-permit-requirement-doctors?0p19G=c